# Receive Payments API V2 Accept bitcoin payments seamlessly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to know how to implement the Receive Payments API V2 Accept bitcoin payments seamlessly into Wordpress, I'm not sure how to put it into WordPress to work and how then to get it to work with Woocommerce. Could someone help me with this? Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? What is your problem?

Comment: I haven't tried it, not sure what direction to go, that is why I have come here to ask. Thank you for your advice I will try it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins that work with Woocommerce and can checkout with Bitcoins.

1.https://wordpress.org/plugins/payment-gateway-stripe-and-woocommerce-integration/ (with using stripe).

2.https://wordpress.org/plugins/gourl-woocommerce-bitcoin-altcoin-payment-gateway-addon/ (used with gourl)

3.ChainPay (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0e5op7ay04o)